# How to decode nested JSON List of Objects in Dart/Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm trying to figure out how I can decode the following JSON in Flutter.

https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.json

I tried the following structure, but it doesn't work.

```
@JsonSerializable()
class StatisticsResponse {
  Map<String, Country> data;
  //List<Country> data;
  StatisticsResponse({this.data});

  factory StatisticsResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$StatisticsResponseFromJson(json);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class Country {
  String continent;
  String location;
  int population;
  //Map<String, Data> data;
  List<Data> data;

  Country({this.continent, this.location, this.population, this.data
  });

  factory Country.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$CountryFromJson(json);
}
```

Comment: Would you please elaborate on what "does not work" mean?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57662221/how-to-parse-a-complexnested-object-to-json-and-send-it-to-server-using-http-i

Comment: There is not a runtime error. The field StatisticsResponse.data is just NULL

Answer (score 0):

Use Map to convert `dynamic` to `String`. Directly assigning List to List will throw an error. You have create getters yourself.

Consider this example:

`(jsonDecode(response.body)["data"] as List).map((e) => e as Map<String, dynamic>)?.toList();`

Now assign to an instance of the custom class you have made.